# How to remove even numbers from an arraylist in c#?

Tags: c#, arraylist

So I'm trying to remove all even numbers from the generated random list I created. But this message keeps showing up: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. What do I need to change?

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    int count = -1;
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            
            numbers[i] = randNum.Next(-100, 100);
  
            array.Add(numbers[i]);
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            //displays random numbers to rich textbox
            richTextBox1.AppendText(array[i].ToString() + '\n');
            
        }
        
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(array[i]) % 2 == 0)
            {
                array.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            richTextBox1.Text = array[i].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are many things wrong here. when you do foreach at that time you can not modify list that you are interating on and also foreach gives you actual element but not the its index.

Comment: You are trying to use the value as the array index: `Convert.ToInt32(array[i])` - just test `i % 2 == 0`. Same goes for `RemoveAt(i)` where you use the value to point to an array index.

Comment: Pick your answer here: [Remove items from array](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+remove+item+from+array+in+foreach+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Also a good time to start learning [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Not using ArrayList would be a good start

Comment: (Something from this century, like List<T> would permit you to use `RemoveAll(x = x%2==0)`)

Comment: Its an assignment, we have to use arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in Button2_click is wrong. You are using foreach loop and then trying to access the index of array using its elements value.
change your second button code with following code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; )
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(array[i]) % 2 == 0)
            {
                array.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
            
        }
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = item +"\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your enumeration like:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(array[i]) % 2 == 0)
        {
            array.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = array[i].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ you can achieve this easily.

```
var oddArray = array.Where(a => a % 2 != 0);
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(", ", oddArray);
```

PS - You just need to add a namespace i.e. `System.Linq`

Comment: For this to work as presented, `array` needs to implement `IEnumerable<T>`; ArrayList doesn't

Comment: Also "making a new collection featuring only odd numbers" might achieve some equivalent end result, but it doesn't "remove even numbers from a list"